# text cropping to the center

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make visible only middle part of the text/symbol(img1 blue lines). By default if there is not enough space inside of a text container then text is cropped only from the bottom side and we'll see only top part of the text. Yeah I know that I can set negative margin but in this case I'll need to set different values depending on the font size but I'd like to make it independent from the font size.

What is it for? I'm using Google material icons font. Some icons are smaller than required(for example arrow_drop_down is very small).in my case best size for it is 1rem but red part of my button(img2) should be much smaller. On img2, the red part should be ~3 times smaller and contain only that triangle.Now red's height = font size.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why can't you wrap the arrow with a span that has a class and give it another font size based on class selector?

Comment: @KAD ok icon becomes bigger. whole transparent box becomes bigger. triangle goes lower and lower. It actually changes nothing

Comment: @KAD added image of expected result

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can be done with adjusting the `line-height`.

Also live examples are always better than bunch of pictures , especially since this example would be easy to set up.